# How can I calculate the memory needed to train a CNN on a single data element using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to calculate the amount of GPU memory needed to train a particular CNN on a particular dataset (or, just in general). The reason is that when I try to train this net, I run out of memory, but cannot figure out why.

I have implemented the following CNN in Tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1491, 257,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 1489, 255, 16)     160       
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 1487, 253, 16)     2320      
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 6019376)           0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 128)               770480256 
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 770482865 (2.87 GB)
Trainable params: 770482865 (2.87 GB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

Storing this model takes `2.87GB`.

Next, I want to calculate the amount of memory required to train this net on a single data element. The input to this net are `1491x257x1` tensors, as indicated by the input shape to the first conv layer. This input comes from wav files that are passed to the net with this data pipeline:

```
data = data.map(preprocess)
data = data.cache()
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
data = data.batch(1)
data = data.prefetch(1)

train = data.take(1)
test = data.skip(10).take(1)
```

where the `preprocess` function converts each wav file into a `1491x257x1` spectrogram image (for thoroughness, I will include `preprocess` and the function it calls at the bottom of this question).

Following explanation in [Calc CNN Memory Consumption](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/cnn-memory-consumption), the amount of memory needed to forward prop a single data element is the amount of memory needed to store that element plus the memory required for the output from each layer of the net.

I believe the memory occupied by  a single data element is `4*(1491*257*1) = 1,532,748 bytes`, since my `input_shape=(1491,257,1)` and I am currently using Tensorflow's default type of `float32`, which has 4 bytes. Similarly, the amount of data needed to store the output of each layer (except for flatten, which is just a rearrangement of the prior layer's output) will be `4 * output dimensions`. This gives the memory needed to forward propagate a single data element as:

```
4*(1491*257*1 + 1489*255*16 + 1487*253*16 + 128 + 1) Bytes
```

or

```
4*(1491*257*1 + 1489*255*16 + 1487*253*16 + 128 + 1)/(1024**3) GB = 0.05 GB
```

So, to train a single image will require total GPU memory of `2.87GB + 0.05GB = 2.92GB`, or `= 2.97GB` if backpropping a single image requires the same amount of memory as fwd propping it.

Next, I want to consider the amount of memory that might be used to store all the data on the GPU.

I'm attempting to reproduce the notebook and results from Kaggle's Bird Audio Classification with Tensorflow ([Kaggle Bird Audio Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/code/lkergalipatak/bird-audio-classification-with-tensorflow/notebook)). Using df -h, I can measure the memory required by the raw files to be `0.4 GB`. Similarly, since the preprocess step converts each file to a `1491x257x1` spectrogram of float32 and there are 810 spectrograms, I know that storing the entire set of spectrograms requires `810 * 4 * (1491 * 257)/(1024 * 1024 * 1024) = 1.15GB`  or since I have a buffer of 1000 data elements, tensorflow might feel it needs `1000 * 4 * (1491 * 257)/(1024 * 1024 * 1024) = 1.43GB`

I can now account for, at most `2.97GB + 0.40 GB + 1.43GB = 4.80GB` Since `9.29GB - 4.80GB = 4.49GB`, I think I should still have more than enough memory to train on a single image without running into an out of memory error. What am I missing here?

---

Detail of functions used in creating TF dataset:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_io as tfio

def preprocess(file_path, label): 
    wav = load_wav_16k_mono(file_path)
    wav = wav[:48000]
    zero_padding = tf.zeros([48000] - tf.shape(wav), dtype=tf.float32)
    wav = tf.concat([zero_padding, wav],0)
    spectrogram = tf.signal.stft(wav, frame_length=320, frame_step=32)
    spectrogram = tf.abs(spectrogram)
    spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=2)
    return spectrogram, label

def load_wav_16k_mono(filename):
    # Load encoded wav file
    file_contents = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    # Decode wav (tensors by channels) 
    wav, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(file_contents, desired_channels=1)
    # Removes trailing axis
    wav = tf.squeeze(wav, axis=-1)
    sample_rate = tf.cast(sample_rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    # Goes from 44100Hz to 16000hz - amplitude of the audio signal
    wav = tfio.audio.resample(wav, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=16000)
    return wav
```

Comment: The optimizer makes a big difference. When you save a model with the optimizer data it is 2 (or 3) times the size. I think it is storing all of the derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` function for auto memory fitting. (ref-> https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#prefetching)

Maybe you'll be interested in my bird sound classification notebook [(76 GB) 160 Polish Bird Sounds Classification w/Ensemble Deep Learning](https://www.kaggle.com/code/banddaniel/76-gb-160-polish-bird-sounds-classification)

You should try;

```
data = data.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
data = data.cache()
data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
data = data.batch(1)
data = data.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```